# Firebase, join paths

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, firebase-security, firebase-util

I have the following data structure:

```
/users/$userId/profile/...
/users/$userId/job/...
/users/$userId/personal/...
```

Suppose that I want to read some data about users' `job` and `profile` and show it as a list. There are 2 (related) problems here:

**1.** How can I set the `.read` security rule. If I say:

```js
"users": { 
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ...
}
```

then the rule cascades. Why can't I replicate the same rule three times under the three different paths? because, then I get an error while joining the paths together. Consider this:

```js
var ref = fbutil.ref();     
var refSearch = new Firebase.util.NormalizedCollection(
                [ref.child('users'), 'usrId']
            ).select('usrId.job', 'usrId.profile').ref(); 
var result = refSearch.orderByChild("profile/name");
return $firebaseArray(result);
```

If I have three different rules under the three paths, the above would fail, because it cannot read the `usrId` itself.

**2.** I'm not sure if using `NormalizedCollection` is the best solution here. Is there any other way to join the 2 paths? This could help solve the first problem as well.

So, how can I join the 2 path (`/users/$userId/profile/` and `/users/$userId/job/`) without making the '/users/$userId' path readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to have a separation between public and private data, make that part of your structure:

```js
{
    "rules": {
        "users": {
            "$user_id": {
                private: {
                    ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid"
                }
                public: {
                    ".read": "true",
                    "job": {},
                    "profile": {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tnx @Jaime, but that doesn't help. As you said, rules cascade, so, there is no need to add $user_id. I'd like to allow users to see other users' profile and job, but not the personal data. The problem is when I try to join the 2 paths. such a join needs read access on `userId`, hence the whole branch

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't understood the intent from your question, edited my answer :)

Comment: Thanks Jaime! It's funny that I had the same structure for other fields but not for users. In my case though (I have other joins from other paths), userIds should be under public/private (duplicated)